# Issues with sending forgot passwords links with Django + AWS SES

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, email, passwords, amazon-ses

I'm trying to add a feature on my Django App to send users who forgot their passwords a link to reset them via email. I'm not sure if I have set up my password reset email feature correctly, or if my AWS SES isn't configured to it.

I have successfully sent email with a verified email in django shell with the method:

`send_mail('title','message','fromsender@mail.com',['toreciever@mail.com])`

Which means that I have configured my environment variables correctly, but incase you need to see it:
Here's my Django Settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'

AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
```

Here are my files

views.py:

```
from re import search
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import SignUpForm, AddRecordForm, RecordFilterForm, CustomUserChangeForm, CustomPasswordChangeForm
from .models import Record
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


#here is the homepage containing all the search filters
def home(request):
    records = Record.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    search_form = RecordFilterForm(request.GET)
    
    if search_form.is_valid():
        search_query = search_form.cleaned_data.get('search')
        university_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('university_filter')
        course_name_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('course_name_filter')
        is_paid_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('is_paid')
        courses_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('course_category')
        duration_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('duration')
        gpa_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('gpa')

        if search_query:
            records = records.filter(
                Q(student_name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(university__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(course_name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(professor_name__icontains=search_query) |
                Q(description__icontains=search_query)
            )

        if university_filter:
            records = records.filter(university__icontains=university_filter)

        if course_name_filter:
            records = records.filter(course_name__icontains=course_name_filter)

        if is_paid_filter:
            records = records.filter(is_paid=is_paid_filter)

        if courses_filter:
            records = records.filter(course_category__iexact=courses_filter)

        if duration_filter:
            records = records.filter(duration=duration_filter)

        gpa_filter = search_form.cleaned_data.get('gpa')
        if gpa_filter:
            records = records.filter(result__startswith=gpa_filter)

    # Pagination
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(records, 15)

    try:
        records = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        records = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        records = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You Have Been Logged In!")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "There Was An Error Logging In, Please Try Again...")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'records': records, 'search_form': search_form})

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You have been logged in successfully!")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid login credentials. Please try again.")

    return render(request, 'login.html')




def profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_records = Record.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
        bookmarked_records = Record.objects.filter(bookmarked_by=request.user)

        return render(request, 'profile.html', {
            'records': user_records,
            'bookmarked_records': bookmarked_records,
        })
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You must be logged in to view that page...")
        return redirect('home')




def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "You Have Been Logged Out...")
    return redirect('home')


def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Authenticate and login
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You Have Successfully Registered! Welcome!")
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})

def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        password_form = CustomPasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid() and password_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            password_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)  # to avoid logging out after a password change
            messages.success(request, "Profile updated successfully!")
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        profile_form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        password_form = CustomPasswordChangeForm(request.user)

    return render(request, 'update_profile.html', {'profile_form': profile_form, 'password_form': password_form})


def delete_user(request):
    try:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Check if the user making the request is the account owner
            if request.user == request.user:
                user = request.user
                user.delete()
                messages.success(request, "Bye Bye!")
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'You are not authorized to delete this account'}, status=403)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'User not authenticated'}, status=401)
    except Exception as e:
        return redirect('home')


def customer_record(request, pk):
    try:
        customer_record = Record.objects.get(id=pk)
        
        # Check if the user has bookmarked the record
        is_bookmarked = False
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            is_bookmarked = customer_record.bookmarked_by.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                messages.success(request, "You must be logged in to perform this action.")
                return redirect('login')

            action = request.POST.get('action')

            if action == 'bookmark':
                customer_record.bookmarked_by.add(request.user)
            elif action == 'unbookmark':
                customer_record.bookmarked_by.remove(request.user)

            return redirect('record', pk=pk)

        return render(request, 'record.html', {'customer_record': customer_record, 'is_bookmarked': is_bookmarked})
    except Record.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "The record does not exist.")
        return redirect('home')




def add_record(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AddRecordForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                try:
                    record = form.save(commit=False)
                    record.created_by = request.user
                    record.save()
                    messages.success(request, "Record Added...")
                    return redirect('home')
                except ValidationError as e:
                    messages.error(request, str(e))
        else:
            form = AddRecordForm()

        return render(request, 'add_record.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return redirect('home')



def delete_record(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        delete_it = Record.objects.get(id=pk)
        delete_it.delete()
        messages.success(request, "Record Deleted Successfully...")
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To Do That...")
        return redirect('home')



def update_record(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_record = Record.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = AddRecordForm(request.POST or None, instance=current_record)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Record Has Been Updated!")
            return redirect('profile')
        return render(request, 'update_record.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return redirect('home')


# custom 404 view
def custom_404(request, exception=None):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)

def notion_templates(request):
    return render(request, 'notion_templates.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def faq(request):
    return render(request, 'faq.html')
```

Urls.py

```
    #password section
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

password_reset_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1> Forgot Password</h1>
    <form method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_done.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>
    We've emailed you instructions for setting your password. If an email exists in our records, you should be receiving it shortly.
</p>

<p>
    If you have not recieved an email in our inbox, then check your spam folder, any spelling mistakes, or the correct email associated with us. 
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_confirm.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% if validlink %}
    <h3>Change Password</h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Change password</button>
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <p>
        This password link has already been used. Please request a new password link.
    </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_complete.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>
    Your password has been set. Click here to return to the Login Screen: <a href="{% url 'home' %}"></a>
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

When I navigate to the password_reset_form.html and enter in verified email it will return the password_reset_confirm.html page. When I navigate to the email, nothing shows. It will return an error if the email isn't verified through aws. (I'm still in sandbox mode I just sent a request to change it to production today.)

If it's these files what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It may sound silly but are u using registered email id. Django didn't throw error even if email id you put for password reset doesn't exist. Just check in your db and doubly sure to use registered email id.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so I have been able to successfully send password reset links in my development environment. I have a deployed django app with a domain but now I get a internal server error when I even try to send any email.